# Determine equality of Datetime values with minute precision within LINQ

Tags: c#, datetime, precision, equality

I need to compare two datetime values to determine equality(exactly the same),using minute precision.Would this be the best way to do it? My dates could have seconds and milliseconds, but i want to consider only down till minutes.

```
       where (Math.Abs(datetime1.Subtract(datetime2).TotalMinutes) == 0)
```

Comment: I'd take that snippet and post it as an answer to your question, that way people can comment / vote up or down on it separately from your question

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Checking whether `Math.Abs(diff.TotalMinutes) == 0` won't do it, no - that's checking whether they're *exactly* the same.

Are you trying to check whether they have the same minute, or whether they're less than a minute apart? For the first, use:

```
where RoundToMinute(dateTime1) == RoundToMinute(dateTime2)
```

having declared:

```
public static DateTime RoundToMinute(DateTime time)
{
    return new DateTime(time.Year, time.Month, time.Day,
                        time.Hour, time.Minute, 0, time.Kind);
}
```

For the second, use:

```
where Math.Abs((dateTime1 - dateTime2).TotalMinutes) < 1
```

You should consider what you want the result to be in the case that one is local and one is in UTC, by the way...

Note that there's nothing LINQ-specific here - assuming you're using LINQ to Objects. If you're using LINQ to SQL, then obviously you can't use local methods, and we'll have to look again...

EDIT: I'm still very unclear on your question. If you need them to be *exactly* the same date/time, it's easy (leaving aside the possible local vs UTC issue):

```
where dateTime1 == dateTime2
```

However, that begs the question of why you mention "minute precision" in the question title or "using up to a minute precision" in the question body.

Comment: Jon - I was wary of using RoundToMinute(datetime) as the incoming dates could possibly have seconds on them and i wanted to maintain a minute precision.Although Math.abs might throw it off as well i guess? I could(should) strip the seconds off before using the dates of course! But to answer your query, yes i do need them to be exactly the same

Comment: @Preetha: If you need them to be *exactly* the same, then in what way do you need "minute precision" as per the question title?

Comment: In case you have datetime values coming in, where you cannot be sure of whether or not they have seconds attached, but all you care about it is whether they are exactly the same..down to the minute. I guess the stripseconds part should be totally seperate and a precede the actual compare of the values..so this would work in that case.

Comment: There's no concept of DateTime "having seconds attached" or not - they *always* have a `Second` value. Maybe that's been set to a meaningful value, and maybe it hasn't - you won't be able to tell. It sounds like my answer probably *is* what you want, but you need to be clear in your mind exactly what you want to happen first. Write some unit tests demonstrating the behaviour you want, then see if my code makes your unit tests pass.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
where (Math.Floor(datetime1.Ticks / 600000000) == Math.Floor(datetime2.Ticks / 600000000))
```

?

Comment: exactly what I thought of when I saw the question

Comment: If you mean `datetime1.Millisecond`, that's not right - the value is always between 0 and 999.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Allen,will do that(still figuring out exactly how the process works!).Here is the code snippet indicating the answer i had come up with initially:

(Math.Abs(datetime1.Subtract(datetime2).TotalMinutes) == 0)

Background: Within my linq query's WHERE clause(hence a one-liner), I need to check if datetime1 and datetime2 are exactly the same. The datetime values under consideration are stamp dates for other values used in the query.

Comment: As edited in my answer, just use dateTime1 == dateTime2. Please update your question to get rid of the "using up to a minute precision" as that isn't the same thing as "exactly the same."