# compare two files based on datetime upto minute?

Tags: c#, linq

I need to compare two files based on datetime upto minute by eliminating seconds while comparing...

```
public class FileCompareLastwritetime : System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<System.IO.FileInfo>
        {
            public FileCompareLastwritetime() { }
            public bool Equals(System.IO.FileInfo f1, System.IO.FileInfo f2)
            {
                return f1.LastWriteTime == f2.LastWriteTime;
            }
            public int GetHashCode(System.IO.FileInfo fi)
            {
                string s = String.Format("{0}", fi.LastWriteTime);
                return s.GetHashCode();
            }
        }
```

Comment: @Marc Gravell:here i am comparing lastwritetime of two files...it will compare upto seconds..i need to compare upto minute..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
public class FileCompareLastwritetime
        : System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<System.IO.FileInfo> {
    public FileCompareLastwritetime() { }
    public bool Equals(System.IO.FileInfo f1, System.IO.FileInfo f2) {
        return ToMinute(f1.LastWriteTime) == ToMinute(f2.LastWriteTime);
    }
    public int GetHashCode(System.IO.FileInfo fi) {
        return ToMinute(fi.LastWriteTime).GetHashCode();
    }
    static DateTime ToMinute(DateTime value) {
        return new DateTime(value.Year, value.Month, value.Day,
                 value.Hour, value.Minute, 0, value.Kind);
    }
}
```

Comment: used jon skeets answer but it is not working for me...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256460/determine-equality-of-datetime-values-with-minute-precision-within-linq

Comment: @bala3569 define "not working"... it does what it claims to; rounds (down) to the minute.

Answer (score 2):

```
Math.Abs(time1.Subtract(time2).TotalMinutes) < 1
```

Comment: Such an `Equals` implementation will fail the required property of transitivity - that `a.Equals(b) and b.Equals(c) => a.Equals(c)`.

Comment: @Ani, It's not mathematical equal implementation, you should think semi fuzzy about this, and I think in this case the true way is this, because i.e comparing creation time by exact minutes is not suitable: a:10:50:00 and b:10:49:50 the minute comparison return false, but for c:10:50:00 and 10:50:50 by exact minute returns true, and IMO it's not a suitable answer. and I think you can't find any good 0-1 equal answer.

Comment: It's a listed guideline. "If (x.Equals(y) && y.Equals(z)) returns true, then x.Equals(z) returns true."  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx

Comment: @Ani, I know what you wanna to say and I think you know what I said, just think about this question leave the MSDN, and if you think in other way we are in opposite sides.